# Are Anointed Siren bonuses activated by variations of Amara action skills?

Tags: borderlands-3

So, Borderlands 3 offers weapons with Anointed bonuses - temporary bonuses which are activated by using action skills. Some weapons require any action skill to be used, but some require specific skills.

Now, Amara is the only character, that has variations of her skills. So, my question is - are variations of skills qualified for anointed bonus activation (e.g. if bonus requires Phaseslam to be used, will it be activated by Fracture, which is Phaseslam variation)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it works. I run Downfall and I get the melee bonus from my guns. Just remember that multiple weapon anointed bonuses don't stack but shield and weapon anointed bonuses do.

Comment: Weird enough - neither Fracture nor Phaseslam itself aren't activating +200% melee bonus on Phaseslam for me (tried for both weapon and shield). Maybe bonus itself is bugged.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It seems to work with grasp and cast on all variations, but not with the slam. Here I only see the anointment triggering, when using the original phase slam :/